# Socket data transfer, "MZ" Appended to buffer? C++ / Java

Tags: java, c++, winsock

I'm sending a file from Server (Java) to client (C++).
While everywhere else the data is recevied just fine. In this area, Sometimes there is "MZ[]" appended to the filename.

Here is the Receving code (C++):

```cpp
else if(command == "freceive")
        {
            // Receive Filename
            int fsize, l = 0;
            WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
            HANDLE hFind;
            char filetoSave[BUFFER] = { 0 };
            std::ostringstream response;
            memset(filetoSave, '\0', BUFFER);
            int fl = recv(sockfd, filetoSave, BUFFER, 0);
            if (fl == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
            {
                connected = false;
            }
            //===================================================
            std::ofstream File(filetoSave, std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
            memset(recvbuf, '\0', BUFFER);
            // Recevie File
            while ((fsize = recv(sockfd, recvbuf + l, sizeof(recvbuf) - l, 0)) > 0)
            {
                if(fsize > 0){
                    File.write(recvbuf, fsize);
                }   
            }
            File.close();


            if(fsize == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
            {
                connected = false;
            }

            File.close();
            if(IsFile((char*)filetoSave) == TRUE){
                hFind = FindFirstFile(filetoSave , &FindFileData);
                if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
                {
                    response << "ERROR Receiving file (" << filetoSave << ") : " << GetLastError();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ULONGLONG FileSize = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;
                    FileSize <<= sizeof( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh ) * 8; 
                    FileSize |= FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
                    response << "Saved : '" << filetoSave << "'\nSize : " << FileSize << " bytes.\nSaved as : " << filetoSave;
                    FindClose(hFind);
                }
            } else {
                response << "Error File not found (" << filetoSave << ") : " << GetLastError();
            }

            EncSend(response.str().c_str());
        }
```

and here is the part of the server which sends the filename (Java):

```java
public static void SendRaw(Socket sock, String data)
    {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = sock.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
            dataOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Everything is going ok except the fact that the filename has `MZ[]` appended to it which I do not want.
Why is this happening? It has given me a headache! Where is this `MZ[]` coming from!?

Here's a screenshot, Note after MZ there is a wierd ascii char like `[]` in absolute filename, But os ignores it.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn3FQ.png)

Comment: if `recv` reads exactly `BUFFER` bytes, then `filetoSave` is not NUL-terminated, and then `std::ofstream File(filetoSave, ...)` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: What you do with `recvbuf` doesn't make much sense. You read into `recvbuf+1`, but you write to the file at `recvbuf`. In effect, you prepend a zero byte to every chunk read. Did you mean it that way?

Comment: Instead of adding making it null terminated I tried receiving a one character less, like ``BUFFER - 1`` which would have the same result. But it still would sometimes add weird characters. Doesn't work. :'(

Comment: No I didn't mean it that way, The `recvbuf` at that part recevies the file, and when done receiving. It's written out. IS there something wrong with it too?

Comment: You seem to assume that each call to `recv` will receive exactly the bytes from one call to  `send` (or `write` in Java case). That's not how it works - TCP is a streaming protocol, there are no boundaries between writes. `recv` will read as much as is currently available. My guess is, your server sends the file name, and then the actual data immediately afterwards, with no delimiter (it so happens that every EXE file starts with `MZ`). Your `recv` then reads the file name and some chunk of the data, mushed together. You need to come up with some protocol for separating the parts.

Comment: Windows PE files (.exe and .dll) start with letters MZ as part of the MS-DOS stub. Are you sure you're not adding some of the file's contents to the filename?

Comment: Why do you pass `recvbuf + l` to `recv`, and not simply `recvbuf`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik wait you're right!! I'll try adding delimiters! And I See what you mean with the `recvbuf` part. I'll test it.

Comment: @Michael Yes that might be the case.